# delay() effective duration interferences from non parent scopes (unpredictable behaviour?)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Good morning,
I discovered that delay inside a library  that make use of coroutines takes way more than the passed value ( which is 5000ms but often takes up to 20 seconds) I initially supposed some library internal issue which was causing continuation to not be called on time.. but I was unable to find that "issue", changed the scope Dispatchers to unconfined in the library changed nothing, ant the cpu usage is very low on all cores ( 5% ) ,
So I've done some tests using the coroutineContext  that library ..

The library context is : `BLACKBOX_ACTOR.coroutineContext`

```kotlin
        val threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)
        fun busyCoreDelay(ms:Int){ // CONF WORKS ALWAYS 
            val tstart=System.currentTimeMillis()
            while(System.currentTimeMillis()-tstart<ms){
                //noop
            }
        }
        withContext( CoroutineName("Test") + Job() +Dispatchers.Unconfined){
            GlobalScope.launch(BLACKBOX_ACTOR.coroutineContext+ Job() + Dispatchers.IO+CoroutineName("Test2") ){ // AA with this DOESNTWORKS
                //GlobalScope.launch(CoroutineName("Test3") + Job() +Dispatchers.Unconfined){ // AB with this WORKS (only if AA is not present!)
                GlobalScope.launch(CoroutineName("Test3") + Job() +threadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher()){ // AC (works with AB , doesn't with AA )
                while(isActive){

                    val tstart=System.currentTimeMillis()
                    //delay(5000) // PROBLEM1
                    busyCoreDelay(5000)
                    val tend=System.currentTimeMillis()
                    val delaydelta=tend-tstart
                    log.warn { "inner delaydelta = ${delaydelta}" }
                }
                }
            }
//
        }
```

the main question is why delay takes more than nominal value even when parent is in unconfined Dispatchers ( this is inside the library, the code is complicated to being posted here, but unconfined dispatcher shouldn't avoid delay() calls to take too much (given cpu almost at 0 ? )

but also... why if I call "delay(5000) // PROBLEM1" with `AA + AB or AA+AC` doesn't works, and with `// AB or AB+AC`  instead works ?

as my understanding the inner job should escape any parent coroutineContext and dispatcher from BLACKBOX_ACTOR
( the busyCoreDelay always works with all configurations )

thank you very much

Comment: What's the contents of `BLACKBOX_ACTOR.coroutineContext`?

Comment: It would be nice if you could tidy up a bit to make your experiments more understandable. Why `PROBLEM1` if there is no `PROBLEM2`? Why AA, AB, AC, and not just A, B, C? `busyCoreDelay` is not necessary to understand the problem in the main snippet of code, it could be provided aside when you mention that replacing `delay` with this function always gives the 5s result. Also please clarify what you mean by "works" or "doesn't work". When it doesn't, do you mean it gives a longer time? Or does it fail in any way?

Comment: Thank you,

there is problem1 and not problem2 because the question has been simplified a bit , the problem2 was the delay inside the BLACKBOX_ACTOR

this BLACKBOX_ACTOR is a somehow complex actor with 4 loops and a channel and some calls to a consul library ,


with a coroutineContext configured as : `BLACKBOX_ACTOR { .... override val coroutineContext = CoroutineName("PartitionAssignator-baseContext") + SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Unconfined  .... }` 

note: Unconfined is used now while trying to looking for this "delayed" delay  causes..without success..

Comment: BUT: why it is important ? , I mean, the immediate calloutside the while(isActive) that you see in this code  ( THE "AC" line )
shouln't escape any parent context ?  I think I am missing something here.. 

busyCoreDelay is here to demonstrate that it's not a starved cpu problem but a continuation point inside the coroutine , busyCoreDelay was my last attempt to see if the BLACKBOX_ACTOR was stuck on something ( if there was contention this would have taken resources from other logic inside BLACKBOX_ACTOR which could have pointed me to the contention issues location )

Comment: @Joffrey I am also now trying to reduce BLACKBOX_ACTOR to the minimum but hasn't yet been able to reproduce the issue in the BLACKBOX_ACTOR alone I am still investigating the issue, I think that the problem is in my comprehension of how coroutineContext works , I still think the delay should be outside of the BLACKBOX_ACTOR corotuineContext because line AC

Comment: I'm pretty confused with all your code for testing, but please be aware when you speak about parent context... well, there is no parent context here. As you use `GlobalScope`, `AC` is unrelated to `AA`, `AB` and to `withContext()` - it runs on its own. Do you maybe launch multiple such coroutines here or use `threadPool` anywhere else? Because I suspect all threads in `threadPool` are occupied, so they can't resume a coroutine after the delay. Maybe your changes between `AA`/`AB` cause the change in how many `AC` coroutines run at the same time or something similar.

Comment: Thank you,I'm confused too by the problem And I understand that the scope of the code to reproduce it it's too large right now,  I am working to narrow down the issue in order to be more easy to reproduce, the 10 threads threadpool is not used elsewhere that's why I don't understand what is interfering with the continuation of the coroutine after the delay (given cpu is in idle ) I'll try to improve the question in coming next days, and again @broot has said I fail to understand  why AC line doesn't work ( given threadpool is free ) I'm investigating that ..

Comment: I understand that the question is so strange I have to produce something reproducible.. I am working on .. and I will tag you both again once done or fixed , thank you

Comment: Well, your question is not strange. It is clear this is a part of some bigger, more complicated logic. Still, it is hard to reason if we can't see it in action. If you can provide a reproducible example, that would be much easier to approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha !
The problem was the usage of `Dispatchers.Unconfined` from an (mine) internal library
this was causing code to be executed on kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor ,
once any code run on `kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor` delay become "unstable"
( it obviously fail to schedule on time given that continuation point is not reached while other code is being executed )

this triggered buggy behaviour in other libraries which timed out upstream calls and so on..

now, I'm gonna mark the question as answered because the problem was actually my mistake in not noticing the use of `Dispatchers.Unconfined` but It may also be helpful to others

( enable the maximum loglevel and look in the program log for code that is executed on `kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor` )

I hope it will also be useful to others who run into the same type of problem,

I want also to thank all the commenters on the original question.